# using lxml and requests in python to grab text between certain tags with a specific class name

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, xpath

I am trying to grab all text between a tag that has a specific class name. I believe I am very close to getting it right, so I think all it'll take is a simple fix.

In the website these are the tags I'm trying to retrieve data from. I want 'SNP'.

```
<span class="rtq_exch"><span class="rtq_dash">-</span>SNP  </span>
```

From what I have currently:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

def main():

    url_link = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^GSPC&d=t"
    page = html.fromstring(requests.get(url_link).text)
    for span_tag in page.xpath("//span"):
        class_name = span_tag.get("class")
        if class_name is not None:
            if "rtq_exch" == class_name:
                print(url_link, span_tag.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":main()
```

I get this:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^GSPC&d=t None
```

To show that it works, when I change this line:

```
if "rtq_dash" == class_name:
```

I get this (please note the '-' which is the same content between the tags):

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^GSPC&d=t -
```

What I think is happening is it sees the child tag and stops grabbing the data, but I'm not sure why.

I would be happy with receiving

```
<span class="rtq_dash">-</span>SNP
```

as a string for span_tag.text, as I can easily chop off what I don't want.

A higher description, I'm trying to get the stock symbol from the page.

[Here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/) is the documentation for requests, and [here](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) is the documentation for lxml (xpath).

I want to use xpath instead of BeautifulSoup for several reasons, so please don't suggest changing to use that library instead, not that it'd be any easier anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some possible ways. You can find the outer `span` and return direct-child text node of it :

```
>>> url_link = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^GSPC&d=t"
>>> page = html.fromstring(requests.get(url_link).text)
>>> for span_text in page.xpath("//span[@class='rtq_exch']/text()"):
...     print(span_text)
... 
SNP
```

or find the inner `span` and get the `tail` :

```
>>> for span_tag in page.xpath("//span[@class='rtq_dash']"):
...     print(span_tag.tail)
... 
SNP
```

Comment: I knew there was an easier way to get something with a given class name

Answer (score 1):

Use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
import bs4

html = """<span class="rtq_exch"><span class="rtq_dash">-</span>SNP  </span>"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
snp = list(soup.findAll("span", class_="rtq_exch")[0].strings)[1]
```

Comment: I do appreciate the effort in providing an answer ... for some reason I have not been able to get the BeautifulSoup libraries to work at all even though I've uninstalled and reinstalled it several times. Troubleshooting this would be a whole different issue for me that I didn't want to get mixed up into this question I was asking. +1 for providing an answer that I'm pretty sure works (just not with me, I tried it)